# UWP - GridView item overlay

Tags: gridview, overlay, uwp

My goal is to create GridView filled with my custom control. Control has two states - closed (70px high) and open (200px high). It contains two grids - 70 and 130. Upper grid is always visible and lower is collapsed by default and has Canvas.ZIndex set to 2.

Every time I expand control it doesn't overlay over other items in GridView - instead, controls pushes them lower. Ho to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

To render controls overlayed on top of the rest of the UI, you will need to use a [`Popup`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.popup). It can be completely customized but requires some supporting code to get it working.

If you are not too demanding, using a [`Flyout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.flyout.aspx) might be enough for you. It is much more restricting regarding its positioning, appearance, and behavior, but also simpler to use:

```
<TextBlock Tapped="UIElement_OnTapped">Closed
    <FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
        <Flyout Placement="Bottom">
            <TextBlock>Opened</TextBlock>
        </Flyout>
    </FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
</TextBlock>
```

In the event handler you can make it visible:

```
private void UIElement_OnTapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var uiSender = sender as UIElement;
    var flyout = (FlyoutBase) uiSender.GetValue(FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyoutProperty);
    flyout.ShowAt(uiSender as FrameworkElement);
}
```

For more information check out [this blog post](https://mareinsula.wordpress.com/2015/12/02/advanced-flyouts-for-uwp-windows-10/) about creating a custom Fylout-like control based on Popup.